# How to add a line into .bashrc? I'm new to Ubuntu system

Tags: software-installation

How do the following instructions follow in Ubuntu system?
Add following line into ~/.bashrc or ~/.cshrc or ~/.tcshrc.

```
 ulimit -s unlimited
```

Answer (score 5):

Open file manager and press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  + <kbd>h</kbd> to show hidden files.

Then, double click the `.bashrc` file to open it (by default, Ubuntu uses bash, and you would not find ~/.cshrc or ~/.tcshrc). Alternatively, right click on it to open it with the text editor.

Now add the line you need to add, and save the file.
Close this terminal and open a new terminal for the changes to take effect (alternatively, enter the command `source .bashrc`, if you don't want to open a new terminal).

Comment: Thanks in advance

Comment: It is enough to close any terminals and reopen one. Logging out then back in would already be overkill, leave alone restarting the computer.

Comment: @vanadium I did not know that. Thanks

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I suggest that, accordingly, you edit your answer and remove the line "Restart the computer". The "Warning" is not specific to this question - I suggest you remove that too.

Comment: @vanadium I have edited as you suggested

Comment: Perfect! Already upvoted yesterday.